# Dailymotion API : Add Video Category

Tags: video, video-streaming, dailymotion-api

I'm able to uploading the video to dailymotion via their data API but the video doesn't get published. 
I figured out that the category of the video has to be set for the video to be published.
I checked the video upload api but there is no option for Category.

Due to this my service is not able to publish the video on dailymotion.

Need help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the channel field

```
curl -d 'title=<TITLE>&channel=<CHANNEL>&tags=<TAGS>' https://api.dailymotion.com/video/<VIDEO_ID>
curl -d 'published=true' https://api.dailymotion.com/video/<VIDEO_ID>
```

The list of channels : https://api.dailymotion.com/channels

Channel in dailymotion is a category not a user.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Once the video is created, it doesn't mean it is published. You have to perform another HTTP POST request on the `https://api.dailymotion.com/video/<VIDEO_ID>` URL along with the fields you want to modify. Some fields like `title`, `tags` and `channel` are mandatory before you can publish the video. Set those fields, and toggle the `published` field to `true` to publish the video.

**Note**: you can perform all these steps in a single HTTP request by passing all the extra information in the initial POST request.